# Update PHP 5.5 to 5.6 (or 7.0) while running Joomla 2.5.8

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, updates, php-5.6

I haven't found answer to my question in the Google, Stackoverflow (using searchbox) or Joomla's support forum.

My problem is: I am running Joomla 2.5.8 website and my Hosting requires me to update PHP version from 5.5 to 5.6. I'd really like to do that because "newer is better" (isn't it?) but I am not sure if it doesn't break my website [as some people have reported](https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=857584).

I could of course update Joomla to 3.x but on the other hand I don't know if it won't break my website either (yet I tried it before - about 1yr ago - and there were some serious problems which didn't break my website but just didn't allow me to update it for some reason I don't remember now; something with license or so[?]).

I could just update the PHP to 5.6 (or 7.0) and just update Joomla's compability by hand checking all deprecated functions and replace them with new ones but list of "[few incopabilities](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php)" ([as php.net call's it](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.php)) isn't job for a weekend considering that I am not creator of Joomla and I don't know it as my own code (actually I quite dislike it).

So do You have any idea what to do in this situation? In the end I can always just throw it all to bin, setup PHP 7.0 server, put newest Joomla on it and build my own template same as the previous one (but still it isn't low-effort solution).

Changing Joomla to other system or create own isn't solution too, 'cause it's not me who is inserting the content and this person knows only this UI...

:(

Comment: Why not clone the site to a machine running php 5.6+ and see what happens?

Answer (score 2):

Does your hosting provide a Cpanel?  If so, go look around under **PHP Configuration**.  Many hosting companies allow you to set a separate PHP version per folder.  So you could create a clone of your website using Akeeba in a folder like /_Testing/, then set /_Testing/ to be on PHP 5.6 and test for problems.

If you do not see that option, contact your hosting and see if they will enable that feature for you.  They might say no, but it is worth asking.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the compability for your extentions on Joomla 3 is a weekend job and as you say "newer is better" or list them here and we can maybe say something about it